# In jsf(xhtml) error while inserting list into selectItem tag

Tags: jsf

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument Error: An option for component TransferToID was not an instance of javax.faces.model.SelectItem.  Type found: java.util.ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is a bit too brief to be acceptable I think, I hope I can guess what's going on. You're binding a list of something to a single selectItem component. This won't work, you need the plural version:

If you're using JSF 1.x, use `Tomahawk`:

```
<t:selectItems value="#{someBean.someList}" var="myItem" itemValue="#{myItem.value}" itemLabel="#{myItem.label}"  />
```

Otherwise (JSF 2.x) just the core components:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{someBean.someList}" var="myItem" itemValue="#{myItem.value}" itemLabel="#{myItem.label}"  />
```

Note that `.value` and `.label` are just examples here. Replace them as appropriate with the properties of the beans that are in your list.